# How to iterate complicated List of Maps containing Maps

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

I'm having problems working out how to iterate this structure.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> list
```

Can you help me work out how to walk the complete structure?

Here's what I've got to so far but where do I go next? I need to get all the way down to the deepest data.

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : data)
     for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
```

Comment: Does it have to be an `ArrayList`? `LinkedList` is more efficient for iterating.

Comment: access for what, it depends what/how the data will be used/accessed, also what have you tried so far

Comment: @Dragondraikk i just want to read all the data.it could be linkedlist also.

Comment: hey @TAsk modified the description :P provide any way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance: Iterating through a List in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642004/performance-iterating-through-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Well with the updated description this question just displays a lack of research. `List.iterator()` and loops are not particularly difficult to google for.

Comment: use list iterator or a for loop or a while loop...all these are normal and efficient ways !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> m : list) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> e : m.entrySet()) {
            String key1 = e.getKey();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> me : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
                String key2 = me.getKey();
                String value = me.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that you really should be using the interface form of the objects:

```
    List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map<String, Map<String, String>> m : list) {
        // All Maps.
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> e : m.entrySet()) {
            // Outer key.
            String key1 = e.getKey();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> me : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
                // Inner key.
                String key2 = me.getKey();
                // The String value.
                String value = me.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
```